# How is my Maven Repository still getting updates?

Tags: maven

New to Maven; I'm working on a project that has been pulling Maven dependencies from a remote repository. I am trying to remove that repository from my project, so that I can switch to using a different one.

I have the repository defined in my pom.xml:

```
    <project>
      ...
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>my-remote-repository</id>
          <url>https://myremoterepository/repo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      ...
    </project>
```

So my assumption is that if I remove this repository reference and remove the dependency files from my local repository, then I should get an error next time I try to rebuild this project, which would prove that I am no longer accessing the remote repository. However, I see that when I rebuild the project, my local repository is still getting updated with the dependency files. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are any repository defined in **./.m2/settings.xml** file?

Comment: The way to go is to configure the repository from which you consume artifacts in your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` ...